Can a product family be compliant with accessibility standards in the USA and Europe?
It’s hard to drill this question down to one question that has one definite answer, but I’ll try.
Can a product family—rather than a product—be compliant with accessibility standards? In the sense that if product A does not conform to a particular criterion, product B does, and vice versa.
I’m particularly interested in compliance with the European Accessibility Act (EAA) and legislation in the United States.
The idea is not that people use both products together, but that both products require certain abilities, like interacting with a voice interface.
So if one product doesn’t have any voice interface, but the other one does, can the family be claimed to be compliant?
I’m aware of two concepts from WCAG that might relate to this. For I believe an interface can still be compliant if

The nature of the product requires certain abilities(f.e. a voice interface like Alexa)
There’s an alternative way to achieve the same outcome in the interface(f.e. a control with a sufficient contrast ratio […] to switch to a presentation that uses sufficient contrast.

Thanks a bunch!

Purely hypothetical: Say, product A is used in Europe and therefore needs voice assistance and product B is used in the USA and doesn't because of different legislation. Is the question if product B needs to have voice assistance as well because it is part of the same product family?

Thanks. I tried to clarify that by editing the question. My question is not about compliance in different countries, but for different products of the same family. In IoT, if you have an app which fulfils all criteria, could you still sell a product which lacks some? Could you claim compliance for the family (which includes the choice of an app?).

I think the term "product family" is not well-defined, and therefore, this question cannot be answered. What do you count as belonging to the same product family?

I think this is a good question but it should focus on the purpose of accessibility and less on the implementation. Because for what I understand now is that it is about specific products for specific target groups, right? For example: Product A is made for most people that have normal vision but the app lacks voice assistance for blind people. While there is a same product (Product B) specifically made for blind people with only voice assistance.

Thanks, that’s the essence of the question, yes.

The EAA (Europe) and ADA (USA) both refer to WCAG for accessibility guidelines as defined by the accessibility standards they follow. I will refer to the accessibility standards followed by the EAA, namely EN 301 549. As stated under chapter 14 (Conformance) in the 2021 document*:

ICT is often comprised of an assembly of two or more items of ICT. In some cases, two or more interoperable items of
ICT may together meet more requirements of the standard when one item complements the functionality of the other
and the sum together meets more of the accessibility requirements. However, combining two items of ICT, both of
which fail to meet any particular requirement, will not lead to a combined ICT system that meets that requirement.

* https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301500_301599/301549/03.02.01_60/en_301549v030201p.pdf
The above is about interoperable ICT: Users depend on both products and if one fails for them, accessibility wise, they can't use the whole combination.
But as follow-up to my comment; if a product is an addition of another product to meet an accessibility requirement, this is a valid approach according EN 301 549. For example following the assessments found under Annex C in the same document (simplified):
C.5.1.3.6: Speech output for non-text content
Pre-conditions 1.

Non-text content is presented to users via speech output.

Procedure 1.

Check that speech output is provided as an alternative for non-text content.
...

It is not mentioned anywhere that the alternative must be in the same product. But I think the combination of products is then to be treated as a single product to meet the requirements, while each individual product is still not (WCAG) compliant. It is a bit of a grey area.
A scenario for C.5.1.3.6 as mentioned earlier: A user lands on the main page of Product A. That page contains an image with important information and there is no text-alternative on that same page. That page doesn't meet WCAG compliance. But if that page has an accessible link specifically for visually impaired people that goes to Product B where the image is provided with speech output, that does meet the intended result in C.5.1.3.6. It's a non-user-friendly approach to accessibility that I don't recommend, but is apparently consistent with that document.

Interesting. Would you mind pointing to the chapters of the EN that you base your reasoning on? Does it define what a product is?

Apparently I was wrong. I edited my answer drastically. The answer is literally in that document.

Edited again to highlight the nuance in the quoted statement from the document.

Thanks so much! Looks like the key is the item, which might be a product.

This regularly happens even within the same product: An iPhone may be CDMA compatible (US-only), or it may be GSM compatible (rest of the world). A Samsung Galaxy phone may be using a Samsung SoC or a Snapdragon SoC. But they're still named the same thing.
Similarly, Google search, Windows, Android and other software have different offerings in different countries. Google search in the EU may no longer have a Google Maps tab, Windows in the EU doesn't do much of the AI stuff, and Android in the EU must ask which browser you want to use the first time you open it up.
I doubt anyone will mind if your SuperBot 4001-EU and SuperBot 4002-US is marketed as "The SuperBot 4000 series is certified accessible" - but ultimately, this is a question for the company lawyer, as this firmly belongs in the unfair competition law playground, rather than a UX question that'd be answerable here.

I’m sorry to have mislead you in the question, but the differences between the countries were not what I was looking for. It was differences in compliance with different criteria in the same country. I hope the question now expresses this more clearly.
